# Is this dotnet vstest equivalent to this dotnet test command?

Tags: .net-core, mstest, vstest, dotnet-publish

I have build and published my .NET Core MsTest test library using this command:

```
dotnet publish .\XunitTestLib\XunitTestLib.csproj -o Tester --self-contained -r win7-x64 /p:UseAppHost=true /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win7-x64
```

I usually run the project with the `dotnet test` command:

```
dotnet test .\Tester\ --filter TestCategory=order --logger trx --results-directory .\TestResults --settings .\XunitTestLib\runsettings.xml
```

I am running the published library with this `dotnet vstest` command as I believe (from the documentation) that a published test library cannot be run using `dotnet test`:

```
dotnet vstest Tester\XunitTestLib.dll --TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=order" --logger:trx --ResultsDirectory:./TestResults --settings:./XunitTestLib/runsettings.xml
```

The `/TestResults` folder is created with the usual subfolders, but no content, and the execution never completes, whereas under `dotnet test` it takes around 1 minute.

Have I mapped from `dotnet test` to `dotnet vstest` correctly?

**[EDIT]**

Turns that the error I'm actually getting is related/similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869609/unable-to-create-new-service-chromedriverservice)...

```
Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:22:52'
System info: host: 'MW12345', ip: '123.456.789.01', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)
```

However, this does *not* happen when running as a regular build (ie: without publishing) under `dotnet test`.

Why would running `dotnet vstest` against the output of `dotnet publish` have this negative effect?

Comment: Why do you say that? Do you have serious reason to believe that it's a failure of the vstest command?

Comment: GitHub is not only a place to report failures, but also questions. For something lacking documentation from Microsoft, its source code and its developers are your best resources.